# How to skip new line character in itext?

Tags: itext

How to skip new line character, if it is already present?

In my case, if my text in database is in this format:

```
Relative to the ground, an airplane 
gains speed when it encounters wind 
from behind.
```

So i have to write in my pdftable column in one line as much space avalible in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `setNoWrap()` true in order to achieve this.
Try something like this

```
Phrase p1=new Phrase("Relative to the ground, an airplane gains speed when it encounters wind from behind.", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,8));
PdfPCell cell1=new PdfPCell(p1);
cell1.setNoWrap(true);
```

Also note that if your column size is less then the text will exceed your cell.